# dimension formula problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, $B_2$ be subspaces
of $V$ such that:
$$\dim A_1 = \dim A_2$$ $$\dim B_1 = \dim B_2$$  and
$$A_1 + B_1 = A_2 + B_2 = V$$ 
Show that there is a linear map $T : V → V$ such that $T(A_1) = A_2$ and $T(B_1) = B_2$.

Is this still true if we drop the very last assumption? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Stuck on this for hours- I'm pretty sure it's a use of the dimension formula-other than that I just am totally clueless

Comment: Suppose $A_1=A_2=B_1\ne B_2$.

Comment: I cant get the question....properly...

Answer (score 2):

It could be handy to know that $\dim(A+B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B) - \dim(A\cap B)$. Then we may start by choosing an isomorphism $A_1 \cap B_1 \xrightarrow{\sim} A_2 \cap B_2$, which is certainly possible, just by choosing bases. Now extend these bases to $A_1$ and $B_1$, resp. $A_2$ and $B_2$, to get the desired map $$T\!: A_1 + B_1 \to A_2 + B_2,$$ again just defined on the bases. For the second part, see the counterexample in Gerry's comment.

Comment: Also worth noting that this answer gives a very good indication of why the counterexample works; if we don't have that extra restriction, $\dim(A_1\cap B_1)$ might be much larger than $\dim(A_2\cap B_2)$.